# f.collection_select from 2 tables in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have in form this code line  `<%= f.collection_select :owner_ids, Owner.order(:id), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>` that returns the list of owners in the massmedium form, but I need in this field also to include the  companies too, so I could have in the same list the companies too, cause a massmedia chanel could be owned by a person or by a company.

**Company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :massmedia, through: :ownerships
  has_many :owners, through: :ownerships
end
```

**Owner.rb**

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :massmedia, through: :ownerships
  has_many :companies, through: :ownerships
end
```

**Massmedium.rb**

```
class Massmedium < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :owners, through: :ownerships
  has_many :companies, through: :ownerships

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= f.select :owners, options_for_select((Owner.all + Company.all)
  .collect{|o| [o.name, "#{o.class},#{o.id}"], {multiple: true}
```

u have to define `owners=(values)` method in your model, which will parse values like ["Company,1","Owner,2"]